# What audio players can use winamp skins?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, appearance

My favorite player is DeaDBeeF - but I am curious whether I can use Winamp skins in a player for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Audacious](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/Audacious) [image: Install Audacious]

This lightweight and highly configurable XMMS fork can be extended with many plugins. It can be customized using "classic" Winamp skins. Different to QMMP which uses Qt Audacious comes based on GTK per default.

#### Audacious GTK:

[image]

#### Classic XMMP view

[image]

#### Winamp iTunes skin

[image]

To install skins download the .wsz files and put them into `~/.local/share/audacious/Skins` (affect your user only) or `/usr/share/audacious/Skins` (affects every user). To change between skins, go to View/Interface preferences.

---

### [Qmmp](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/Qmmp) [image: Install Qmmp]

can use 2x winamp skins, most of them fit very well.

Under Settings/Appearance - Add

[image]

or copy the .wsz files to `~/.qmmp/skins`

[image]

[image]

Comment: have unified the answers

Comment: @cipricus: Questions like your's may gain additional value from different vote counts when they stay separate. And, you lost my upvote. I'd probably had left them separate. Just saying...

Comment: you see, i like one big good answer that i may set as definitive ;) and maybe the question would get upvotes too